# can I deploy local build to docker swarm in virtual machine?

Tags: docker

I am learning Docker and trying to follow the Docker tutorial and am in step 4 [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/).

Basically in this step, we are creating 2 VMs for docker swarm: 1 as swarm manager and 1 as swarm worker.

I think it pulls docker-hub pushed image to the virtual machines to get the service working in swarm. Problem is I am not pushing my built image to docker hub.

My question is, can I use local build to deploy to the swarm VM?

I tried to change `image` line the example `docker-compose.yml` to `build` like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    # image: friendlyhello
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

it of course does not work, which is why I am asking if there is a way to do this?

Comment: I kinda solve this problem of mine. I just `scp` the necessary files to build the images to the VMs and build the image in the VMs before running the `docker swarm`. So this question already got answer (kinda). But if anybody knows any alternative method to build swarm without pushing image to docker repo, I am more than happy to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a local registry on the vm or your local machine and push/pull images from local repo

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Then name/tag your images using

```
localhost:5000/Image_Name:Tag
```

Then push images using

```
docker push localhost:5000/Image_Name:Tag
```

This will  let you save your images in a local registry that your swarm can use without pushing to dockerhub

Comment: cool. I will need to try this first. I read somewhere in docker about private registry but I didnt know it was meant to be local.

Comment:  really easy to setup and use, happy to help if you need help getting it setup